# Is there a way in Qt to get all widgets on a form?

Tags: c++, qt

For example I have 20 widgets on a form. I need to resize them based on screen resolution so here's my method

```
newHeight=(desktopHeight * ui->widget1->height())/768;
newWidth=(desktopWidth * ui->widget1->width())/1024;
newY=(desktopHeight * ui->widget1->y())/768;
newX=(desktopWidth * ui->widget1->x())/1024;
ui->widget1->setGeometry(newX,
              newY,
              newWidth,
              newHeight);
newFontSize=(desktopHeight * ui->widget1->font().pointSize())/768;
ui->widget1->setFont(QFont ("Ubuntu",newFontSize, QFont::Bold));
```

And I will repeat this method for the remaining 19 widgets. Is there a way to get all of the widgets and create a do while statement and create a function that the widgets are the parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are all the widgets attached to a form or window?

You can just grab all the child widgets from their UI parent widget and iterate over the collection of children.

Depending on your widget hierarchy you should just do something like

```
QObjectList *widgetList = parentWidget->findChildren();
```

In your specific case:

```
QObjectList *widgetList = ui->centralWidget->findChildren();
```

Edit: Without the rest of your code I have no idea what ui represents, hence my generic answers. I was assuming your ui was a MainWindow as follows in my code

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
        ui->setupUi(this);

        QObjectList widgetList = ui->centralWidget->children();
        qDebug() << "Amount of children found :" << widgetList.count();

}
```

Comment: just call findChildren on your parent node, ui, and then iterate over the QObjectList altering each child as you go

Comment: i try it but im getting these error
error: expected primary-expression before '*' token'widgetList' was not declared in this scope

Comment: did you `#include QObjectList`

I just tested this by creating a default GUI app and ran it in the mainwindow constructor. Worked fine

Comment: yes i put this #include <QObjectList> at the top of my cpp file. after i remove the qDebug before your code this is the remaining  error: invalid use of member (did you forget the '&' ?) and  base operand of '->' is not a pointer

Comment: This is likely due to how you've passed your ui into the method you're doing this code in. I'm not here to troubleshoot your entire project. I've answered the question you asked. 

why not try `ui.centralWidget->findChildren();` instead.

Comment: i cant find the ui.centralwidget, when i type ui-> i only see all of the ui. and some functions.

Comment: "All of the ui". One of those should be the MainWindow or the parent of all your other widgets

Comment: do you mean the name of the ui? i dont understand so im trying this->findchilder() but still have errors even i included the qlistobject. sorry we had our lunch break in d office.

Comment: im using qt 4.7.3 i make the parentwidget->findchildren() to parentwidget->findchildren and still got errors

Comment: also there is no geometry properties when accessing the widgetlist. i already put it on first position for example.

Answer (score 2):

reggie! Don't you think that you are doing it wrong?

**About layouts**

Your approach is used for very specific cases, because there are ready-to-use from the box solution in Qt, called Layout management.

Here you can read about it: [Layout Management](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html), also, see [example of usage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-layouts.html) and intuitive how-to [use it in Qt designer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-layouts.html)

**About fonts:**
There is `QApplication::setFont`, so you can change font program-wide.
But in official documentation you can find:

> This function lets you override the default font; but overriding may be a bad idea because, for example, some locales need extra large fonts to support their special characters.

Comment: You are confusing between the layouting and sizing. As I know, there are no ways in Qt to make resolution-independed UI, based on widgets. If you have some - I may ask question and offer bounty for it.

Comment: yes yes im talking about the sizing when im using 1024x768 the ui are fit on the screen and then when i changed into 800x600 the ui are not fitted to screen so i need to resize it based on screen resolution and there's my formula. i need to create a dynamic function where in i can resize any widget on a certain form.